# Javascript search is working in sharepoint 2007 and not in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, csom

Javascript search is working in sharepoint 2007 and not in sharepoint 2013. Is there version problem?

Comment: What search are we talking about here, can you share some code? In SharePoint 2013, there are architectural changes in Search. Most important is that Scopes are gone which used to be in 2007 and 2010 I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there can be differences in the API (since there are mor than 6 years technological Progress).

Comment: And what should you do to overcome the problem?

Comment: Debug the existing code, find the error and reimplement (or reimplement at all, as there might be better ways after 6 years)